# how can i know the user name that created the registry key in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE

Tags: python, windows, registry

how can i know the user name that created the registry key in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE. And how can I get the above username using python?
Example:

```
key :HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\BCD00000000\Description
username: BUILTIN\Administrators
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the current owner of a key, which may be a group (e.g. administrators), but not the user that created it. For example, using the PyWin32 package:

```
import win32security

sd = win32security.GetNamedSecurityInfo(r'MACHINE\BCD00000000\Description',
        win32security.SE_REGISTRY_KEY, win32security.OWNER_SECURITY_INFORMATION)
owner_sid = sd.GetSecurityDescriptorOwner()
owner_name = '\\'.join(win32security.LookupAccountSid(None, owner_sid)[1::-1])
```

`GetNamedSecurityInfo` supports local and remote registry keys (e.g. "\\ComputerName\CLASSES_ROOT\SomePath"), and the predefined registry keys use the following names: "MACHINE", "USERS", "CLASSES_ROOT", and "CURRENT_USER".

Comment: Use a tool such as process monitor. The process path can provide hint.  Or enable auditing on registry.

Comment: @ddbug, the question was to know what user in general created a registry key, which may have been created at any time in the past, not how to enable monitoring or auditing of the registry API at the kernel level. The data in the registry key itself simply does not provide this information. It has an owner SID, which can be a user or group, and which can be changed arbitrarily (assuming SeRestorePrivilege) at any time. I discussed this with tung in a comment, and tung said that getting the current owner of the key was actually the desired answer, so I moved by comment into an answer.

Comment: @ErykSun could you email me. I'd like to hire you.